# Embedding specific Python

Tags: python-3.5, python-embedding

I am currently embedding Python3 into my C++ application.

We also ships a defined version of Python3. Currently `Py_Initialize` finds the system python in `/usr/lib/python3.5` (which we do not want). I could not yet figure out how I can strip the search path before calling `Py_Initialize` and force it to search in my custom path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with `Py_SetPythonHome`.